# I have a simple javascript issue

Tags: javascript, mobile

In a jquery mobile form, I have a javascript for calaculate the shipping and handling costs :

```
function shippinghandling(val){
//  val1=val.valeur.value;
var str = ""+val.valeur.value;
    val1 = new Number(str.replace(",", "."));

handling = 165;

if(val.rate1[1].checked) {
    rate=125;
    val.shipping.value=Math.max(parseInt(((val1*rate)+0.005)*100)/100,24.79);  
}
if(val.rate1[0].checked) {
    rate=60;

    if(val1 >  handling){
        val.shipping.value=Math.max(parseInt(((handling*rate)+(125*(val1-handling)))*100)/100,24.79);   
    }else{
        val.shipping.value=Math.max(parseInt(((val1*rate)+0.005)*100)/100,24.79);  
    }
}
```

It works fine.
I want now to fine tuning it by adding the ability to calculate the handling cost regarding the zip code of the client.

Here is the zip input field in the form :

```
<input name="zip" type="text" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Enter your zip code" value="" maxlength="4" id="zip">
```

Here is the zipcontrol function :

```
function zipcontrol(zip) {

if(zip==1234 || zip==5678 || zip==9876 || zip==5432) 
{
handling.value=217
}
else handling.value=165
};
```

Of course, it doesn't work as I'm super dummy in javascript...
Could someone help me ?

I know the code above is maybe stupid but I try my best, sorry.

Thank you in advance
Thommen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this:

```
function zipcontrol(zip) {
    if(zip=="1234" || zip=="5678" || zip=="9876" || zip=="5432") return 217;
    return 165;
}
```

And in your first code, you change

```
handling = 165;
```

for

```
handling = zipcontrol(document.getElementById("zip").value);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Romain for your help !
I don't know if or where the zip variable must be declared...
I've tried your code and I think I miss something because the handling is always 165 either if the zip is 1234. 
Is the problem where is the zip declared ?